# ReferenceError: variable is not defined.. again

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, return

I'm new at this so please be kind but I'm totally open to constructive criticism.

I need help making sure this function is running properly.  when i try to console.log(var) i keep getting var is not defined.

This function should accept an array of dwarf names.
It should then return a string with the numbered dwarves. The string should look like this: "1. Doc 2. Dopey 3. Bashful 4. Grumpy "

I've searched around but can't seem to find any answers.

```
function dwarfRollCall(dwarves) {
  var names = [ "Dopey", "Grumpy", "Bashful"]
  var dwarfNames = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if(i === names.length+1) {
            dwarfNames += (i+1 + ". " + names [i]);
        }else {
            dwarfNames += (i+1 + ". " + names [i] + " ");
        }
    }
    return dwarfNames;
}
```

Comment: The code you've included, shouldn't produce that error....

Comment: You seem to be missing some code. How are you calling the function and what are you using for `console.log(var)`?

Comment: sorry, the console.log(var) was an example.  I've tried console.log(names), and console.log(dwarfNames) and receive the same error message.

Comment: are you using console.log inside the function body?

Comment: no.  outside, I'm using RunJS trying to run code line by line.  A lot of this stuff is pretty new so I apologize if I'm not very clear in verbalizing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Are you assigning `dwarfRollCall()`'s return value to a variable before attempting to log it? For example, you should be doing something like `var dwarfNames = dwarfRollCall(dwarves); console.log(dwarfNames)` and not just `dwarfRollCall(dwarves); console.log(dwarfNames)`.

Comment: @john Please post the entire code you are running, you can [edit] your question. And yes, those variables are local to the function, you cannot log them from outside.

Comment: @jdgregson I figured it out!! Thank you! I removed the console.log(*) and everything worked.. cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like:

```js
const inputArr = ["Doc", "Dopey", "Bashful", "Grumpy"];

function dwarfRollCall(arr) {
    let str = '';
    arr.forEach((elem, i) => {
        str = `${str} ${i+1}. ${elem}`;
    });
    return str.trim();
}

console.log(dwarfRollCall(inputArr)); //1. Doc  2. Dopey  3. Bashful  4. Grumpy
```

Hope this helps :)